# Ms Access 2010 error using function in query when using db for 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access, migration

Using Access 2007 with db saved as Access 2003
I have table Table1 with one Field MyDate.
When running a query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.MyDate < Date()
```

have an error `<Message> in query expression <expression>. (Error 3075)`

When using this query in Db saved at 2010 Access, is OK.
Any Ideas?

**Update:** Using Access 2007 with Access 2003

Comment: Can you post up the structure of Table1?  Is MyDate a date field?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Yes, it have one Field MyDate of type date/time.

Comment: This has run fine for me.
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.MyDate < Date()

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Problem in using functions in queries in this Access versions combination, not only Date() fails. I tried to use queries from Mircosoft examples, when I change Date() to #1/1/2014# it works

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Have you saved Db in 2003 Access and using 2010 Access?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't.  This appears to be a problem with locale settings (d/m/y vs m/d/y formats).

Comment: Hm, It is problem of the particular data base. Trying found out what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that problem is in the particular database.

Problem was solved when I resaved db. Strange behavour...